# On connecting to MySQL via SSL getting ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: protocol version mismatch

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl

I am working with MySQL and generated the certificates to use with MySQL to enable SSL.

Here are SSL configs:

```
mysql> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                      |
+---------------+----------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                        |
| have_ssl      | YES                        |
| ssl_ca        | /etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem     |
| ssl_capath    |                            |
| ssl_cert      | /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                            |
| ssl_key       | /etc/mysql/server-key.pem  |
+---------------+----------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It seems to be working fine and looks like I did it well with applying the certificates with the MySQL server.

The problem exists with creating connection to MySQL server via remote host.

```
mysql -u app1 -p -h 192.168.33.131 --ssl --ssl-capath=<path>/ssl/ --ssl-ca=<path>/ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=<path>/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=<path>/client-key.pem
Enter password:
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: protocol version mismatch
```

Seems to be having some issues with certificates or may be something else.

**Environment:**

```
  OS:      Ubuntu 14.04
  MySQL:   5.5.41
  OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/194074/ http://www.percona.com/blog/2012/11/08/debugging-mysql-ssl-problems/ https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64870

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: How is a question about a problem while making a connection to a MySQL database in a programming language "not about programming"?

Answer (score 3):

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64870

At the bottom:

> If you're using 'openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 ...' to generate keys,
>   please be advised that openssl 1.0 and newer now stores private keys
>   in the PKCS#8 format instead of PKCS#1.
>
> Make PKCS#8 the default write format for private keys, replacing the
>        traditional format. This form is standardised, more secure and doesn't
>        include an implicit MD5 dependency.
>        [Steve Henson]
>
> These keys will have a PEM header such as:
>
> ```
> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
> ```
>
> If MySQL is compiled with YaSSL as its SSL implementation (which I
>   believe is the default), these keys won't load and MySQL will complain
>   at startup:   [Warning] Failed to setup SSL   [Warning] SSL error:
>   Unable to get private key
>
> YaSSL expects RSA private keys in the PKCS#1 format, with the PEM
>   header:
>
> ```
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> ```
>
> Various "advices" online seem to suggest that you can change the PEM
>   header and footer of those PKCS#8 private keys to get them to work
>   with MySQL/yaSSL.  That will indeed stop MySQL from complaining at
>   startup, but unfortunately SSL connections against MySQL will still
>   fail with something like:
>
> ```
> **ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: protocol version mismatch**
> ```
>
> To fix this, convert the key to the older PKCS#1 RSAPrivateKey format
>   using 'openssl rsa'. 
>   `$ openssl rsa -in key-from-openssl-1.pem -out pkcs1-yassl-compatible-key.pem`